# C#: The type or namespace name 'class' could not be found(are you missing a using directive for an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, object

```
class World
{
    bool _playerHasWonGame = false;
    public void Update()
    {
        Entity player = FindEntity("Player"); //ERROR: The type or namespace name 'Entity' could not be found(are you missing a using directive for an assembly reference?)
    }

    private Entity FindEntity(string p) //Same ERROR
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}



class Inventory
{
    public bool Contains(Entity entity)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

The error part is Entity.

I create Entity class, and try to make Entity object in World class.

As I understood, it should work. I just tried to make object like other C# programmer does. But, looks like my compiler cannot find Entity definition.

Comment: Post the stacktrace please and are the above classes in the same namespace?

Comment: This is a compiler error, so there would be no stack trace.

Comment: are you sure you need public before class Entity? it's not Java you are dealing with. all classes are public.

Comment: @Gajet, no, in C# classes declared at namespace scope default to internal access.

Comment: @Alex: Can you show us the exact error message, also, are both `World` and `Entity` in the same namespace?

Comment: @ ClassicThunder: Yes. All of those classes are under same namespace. @ Josh Petrie: Actually, this code comes from the book named "C# Game Programming: For Serious Game Creation". I have an sample code from CD of the book. Mine and this sample code are exactly same. However, somehow my compiler cannot fine definition of Entity. @Gajet: I actually add it because I thought that this might help to solve error. I thought my compiler somehow cannot fine the definition of Entity due to visibility. However, It still has error. So, I assume this is not about visibility.

Comment: @Skalli: The error is "The type or namespace name 'Entity' could not be found(are you missing a using directive for an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Skalli: Yes it is in the same namespace, same project. I made thoses classes from right-click on Solution -> Add new Item -> class

Comment: I can't replicate this locally. Have you tried a rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

Classes are not public by default, so `Inventory` is less accessible than the property which is returning an instance of it.

Either change `Entity` to be internal (so it and its properties will exist in the same scope as `Inventory`) or make `Inventory` public.

(With either change the snippet compiles for me)

Comment: +1 The issue isn't that `Entity` is fine but there's some weird accessibility issue. The issue is that `Entity` won't compile, so it can't be referenced.